# How to create a large icon tray?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

How can I create a large icon tray (ex: 32x16) that can show a text number with 3 digit or more using c# ?
any code example will be very appreciated.

Comment: You can try putting two side by side. You can't guarantee that Windows won't split accross mutliple rows though.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Notification area icons are 16x16, or a little bigger if you have font scaling. They have to be square.